# Is there any difference between using AVPlayer, AVPlayerItem, and AVPlayerAsset?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avasset, avplayeritem

I found the three ways to play video with URL.

```
let url = "some url"

// first way
AVPlayer(url: url)

// second way
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

// third way
let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
```

Is there any difference between above these?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs of [`AVPlayer.init(url:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1385706-init)

> This method implicitly creates an `AVPlayerItem` object. You can get the player item using `currentItem`.

So we know that when you use the first way, something similar to the second way is happening under the hood - an `AVPlayerItem` will be created with the URL you specified. Therefore, the first and second way are the same.

Although the docs doesn't say this explicitly, I'm pretty sure `AVPlayerItem.init(url:)` creates an `AVAsset` using the URL you specified too, since an [`AVPlayerItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem) is:

> An object used to model the timing and presentation state of an ***asset*** played by the player.

The wording suggests that you can't have a `AVPlayerItem` without a `AVAsset`. Indeed, `AVPlayerItem.asset` is a non-optional property. So you really need an `AVAsset` to create an `AVPlayerItem`. That, combined with the fact that `AVPlayerItem.init(url:)` is a convenience initialiser, and [`init(asset:automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1387529-init) is the designated one, I am quite sure `AVPlayerItem.init(url:)` creates an `AVAsset` under the hood as well.

If you are wondering why `AVPlayer.init(playerItem:)` and `AVPlayerItem.init(asset:)` exist when all three ways do the same thing anyway, they are for when you just so happen to be working with `AVPlayerItem`s when you want to create a `AVPlayer`, and when you just so happen to be working with `AVAsset`s when you want to create an `AVPlayerItem`.